# Outputting everything in specified row in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

So I need to output everything on a specified row in a excel datasheet, so far I can open the sheet and output everything in that row by inputting the number of the row (in the while loop). But not all my sheets have the name in the same row so I need something to search for the name (ex name FIND) and output everything under it. Is there a way to do this?

```
 import xlrd
 file_Location ="location of file"
 workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_Location)
 sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('name of the sheet im using')
 num_rows = sheet.nrows-1
 curr_row = -1

 while curr_row < num_rows:
     curr_row +=1
     row = sheet.cell(curr_row,16)
     print row.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now it seems like your code is printing values from different rows on a same column, and not the opposite as you stated. If that is what you want, you could use a for loop to check the value on every column on the first row (also assuming that is what you want). Something like:

```
for curr_col in range(50):
    col = sheet.cell(0, curr_col)

    if col.value == 'FIND':
        break
```

And then you would use curr_col in your next loop:

```
while curr_row < num_rows:
    curr_row +=1
    row = sheet.cell(curr_row,curr_col)
    print row.value
```

If the row where you have the names is not the very first one on your spreadsheet (value 0 in python), change

```
col = sheet.cell(0, curr_col)
```

to

```
col = sheet.cell(X, curr_col)
```

where X would be the row you want.